# Accessing a Java RMI API from Python program

Tags: java, python, rmi

I have a Python program that needs to access a Java RMI API from a third party system in order to fetch some data.

I have no control over the third party system so it MUST be done using RMI.

What should be my approach here? I have never worked with RMI using Python so I'm kind of lost as to what I should do..

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Ok, here is what you need to do: 1. Get the original RMI Classes
2. Call [rmic](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/tooldocs/solaris/rmic.html) with the ```-idl``` flag to generate an IDL file
3. See [the instructions here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/rmi-iiop/rmi_iiop_pg.html) and connect to your java App using RMI-IIOP (also, a search for omniorb java iiop might help you as well)

Comment: There in no such thing as accessing Java RMI from Python. You will have to write some middleware.

Comment: He says he can't change the Java end at all.

Comment: Actually, given the defaults (VM >= 1.5), its quite possible to work out of the box

Comment: yeah that's what I was afraid of... guess I'm going to need to write something in Java..

Comment: @aldrinleal Unless the Java application is already using RMI/IIOP, 'rmic -idl' is not an answer, as he cannot change the Java application. I have no idea what 'defaults' you are referring to. RMI does not default to IIOP in Java 1.5 or any other version. It will not 'work out of the box'. You are mistaken.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about a little java middle ware piece that you can talk to via REST and the piece in turn can to the remote API?

Answer (score 2):

You're going to have a *very* hard time i would imagine.  RMI and Java serialization are very Java specific.  I don't know if anyone has already attempted to implement this in python (i'm sure google knows), but your best bet would be to find an existing library.

That aside, i would look at finding a way to do the RMI in some client side java shim (maybe some sort of python<->java bridge library?).  Or, maybe you could run your python in Jython and leverage the underlying jvm to handle the RMI stuff.

Comment: "i'm sure google know" ... this is the first link that shows up on google.